# Why this is happening to me? vs Why is this happening to me?

Tags: verbs, questions, pronouns

> 1) Why this is happening to me?
>
> 2) Why is this happening to me?

Which is correct while speaking (not written English)? Which native english speakers user mostly?

Comment: @snailboat they link you posted talks only about written english. My question is about spoken English.

Comment: The answers there describe both written and spoken English.  There's no distinction to be made in this context.